# ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined after upgrading to JSF2.2 and RF4.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, richfaces, jsf-2.2

After upgrading a Java application from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.2 and Richfaces 3.3.3.Final to Richfaces 4.5 and Facelets 1.1.14 to 1.1.15 I cannot load JQuery in my XHTML page.  The function below is not executed and the HTML page does not size the border as indicated.

It throws an error as follows, visible in Firebug when calling this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeWrapper() {
        // maximum width of bd: subtract 20 for wrapper padding, 4 for bd border, 20 for bd padding
        var width = jQuery(window).width() - 44;

        // round down to nearest 100, adding 24 for bd box
        jQuery('#wrapper').width(Math.max(width - width % 100, 900) + 24);
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(resizeWrapper);
    jQuery(window).resize(resizeWrapper);
</script>
```

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined --> jQuery(document).ready(resizeWrapper);

This was working previously so I know it has something to do with the upgrade.  I was using this previously in the xhtml body (at the top):

`<a4j:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js"/>`

I've made updates to the faces-config and web.xml to support the upgrade and resolved errors related to outdated configuration.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be new to plain HTML/JS. You have nowhere confirmed if the generated HTML output looks right. I.e. the `<script>` referring jQuery file is there, and it is located before your `<script>` with that `jQuery` call, and the browser retrieved a proper response on that. Rightclick in browser and do *View Source* to verify one and other. JSF is in this regard "just" a HTML code generator. Once you find the culprit then it's technically a matter of rewriting JSF code in such way that it produces the desired HTML output.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response.  I'm new to JSF, Richfaces and Facelets.  I've updated my post.  The function above does not work due to JQuery error above.  So my question is, what is required after upgrading JSF1.2 to JSF2.2 and RF3.3.3 to RF4.5 to get this to work?  If I'm missing anything else that can help clarify my problem let me know.

Comment: This problem is not strictly JSF related. With the necessary basic HTML/JS knowledge, you'd have asked this question in a different format. Again, check HTML source, check browser console, etc for clues.

Comment: You don't need load jquery, it is part of RichFaces jar (see inside `richfaces-core-impl-4.X.Y.Final.jar`)

Comment: Hi Vasil, thanks for your constructive feedback.  This is also my understanding.  However after the JSF and RF upgrade I need to remove the line: <a4j:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js"/> as it is no longer relevant.  However, I still receive the error above.  Any ideas?

Comment: @BalusC, I take on board your feedback for future questions.  I've gained value from some of your other posts - JSF in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause.  It was due to a typo I introduced to the web.xml.  After this was corrected I no longer had the issue.  So if you're experiencing an error similar to the above when upgrading from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.2, be sure to check you don't introduce new issues when updating the web.xml file :)